# Mongo get db.serverstatus from casbah

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

Is there a way to get the results of

```
db.serverStatus()
```

from *casbah* to handle them?

I specifically need the connections, network, metrics fields.

Thanks

Comment: sounds like http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.1.5.0/scaladoc/#com.mongodb.casbah.MongoDB the stats method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._ 

    //connect to MongoDB, testDB is the name of database
    val test = MongoClient()("testDB")
    // run serverStatus command
    val status = test.command("serverStatus")
    // status is an instance of BasicDBObject 
    //retrieving number of available connections
    val availableConnections = status.get("connections").asInstanceOf[BasicDBObject].get("available")
```

Comment: @ whoever reported this answer. Please write a comment to such answers, I have no idea what's wrong with this answer.

Comment: I'll try it first thing tomorrow. 
Thanks in advance ;)